# WPF TextBlock Bind to code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a CS code like this:

```
public static string days(DateTime fromDate)
    {
       switch (fromDate.DayOfWeek)
        {
            //Weekdays
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                return "Wednesday";
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                return "Thursday and Friday";
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                return "Saturday";
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                return "Sunday and Monday";
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                return "Tuesday";
            //Weekends
            default:
                return "-";
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to bind it to a text block:

```
<TextBlock Name="days" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="625,230,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="159" Height="21" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Can you help me how to do that?

Comment: You can only bind to public properties. Read this first: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview).

Comment: You could try using a Converter, but that would be a long stretch. Still, you would need a Notifiable property.

Answer (score 0):

Either set the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` directly:

```
days.Text = days(DateTime.Now);
```

Or call the days method from a public property of your view model and bind to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You make a property DayNow
`public string DayNow { get; set; }`
After, you set value for it `DayNow = days(DateTime.Now)`
And binding in view you add this property `Text="{Binding DayNow}"` for `TextBlock`.